# Mklink File Type Link Chrome Browser Downloading Files

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, symbolic-link, mklink

How do you use mklink to make PDF Files when downloaded go to a certain directory.

I want only that file type to go to a directory in my documents folder called PDF

So each time i download a PDF File with say chrome broswer it will download to the set directory for that file type.

I already have installed

Downloads Router

But cant work out the MKLink required

I want it to work with PDF Files to the folder of choice Download Router configured for applications/pdf 
the example below is for mpegs but i want it for pdfs to go to a certain directory

Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as Administrator
Search for cmd in the start menu, right-click and choose 'Run as Administrator'
Create the symbolic link: mklink /D TARGET LINK
Substitute TARGET for the link name within Downloads, and LINK to your desired download destination
Example: mklink /D "C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Music" "D:\Music"
Configure Downloads Router, setting your Destination folder to TARGET.
Example: Filetype (MIME) = audio/mpeg, Destination folder = Music/

Thank you

Comment: Are you following a guide explaining how this is to be set up?

Comment: Yes but i cant work it out.. I did the Downloads Router part but it requires that you do the MKlink for the pdf files to go to a directory of choice

Comment: Then we need to know what guide you tried following, what steps you've done.

Comment: I want it to work with PDF Files to the folder of choice
Download Router configured for applications/pdf


Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) as Administrator
Search for cmd in the start menu, right-click and choose 'Run as Administrator'
Create the symbolic link: mklink /D TARGET LINK
Substitute TARGET for the link name within Downloads, and LINK to your desired download destination
Example: mklink /D "C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Music" "D:\Music"
Configure Downloads Router, setting your Destination folder to TARGET.
Example: Filetype (MIME) = audio/mpeg, Destination folder = Music/

Comment: All of this information needs to be in the question. Please use the edit button to add this and the other information we've requested to the question itself.

Comment: I have added it to the question.. thank you

Comment: Anybody have a the solution? thank you